# My question isn't a good match for Stack Overflow. On reflection it might be a better fit, here. Would like to check first

Tags: discussion, support

Question is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71924013

Its about being a responsible site manager/owner, rather than coding the site. Questions related to the correct/appropriate/best practice management of a website, by its owner/manager, seem better suited here, and the site's content guidance suggests it may fit. So I'm hopeful it'll be allowed, given the importance and general wide applicability of the issue.

Appropriate/better match here? (If not, then which stack?)

Thanks!

**Update - [posted here now](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/139194), thanks for help, hope I got it right? If not, please explain what more to fix. Thanks either way for hand-holding so far.

Comment: Thanks for checking here first. The subject is [on-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as Stephen pointed out, but the question itself is [too-broadly scoped and will likely lead to subjective discussions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) instead of factual answers, as John pointed out. Due to the format of this site with voting and "accepted" answers, the later doesn't really fit too well. So if you can edit it to seek more factual answers as both stated, then it would likely be considered on-topic and better fit here too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it would be appropriate here on Webmasters. Questions about your website in the context of the wider world are on-topic here. Our [charter](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explicitly calls out "internet marketing" for your website as something that is on-topic. Ensuring that your site is classified appropriately by child protection filters is in that same vein.

You should delete the question on Stack Overflow and copy and paste it to Webmasters.  Only the Stack Overflow moderators have the ability to move your question. However, unless your question has answers that are worth migrating with it, they decline to do so.  The preferred migration path for unanswered questions is delete, copy, and paste.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do so once the matter raised by John Conde is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The question as it is currently written is too broad. You have multiple questions, some of which are very broad and bad for this format. If you want to specifically know how to have your site identified as an adult site, and thus filtered by software, that would be a great question for this site. But you will obviously need to modify your question before posting it here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. There's only 2 questions, and they are tightly related. But perhaps its a matter of layout/clarity. The questions are (1)  What's the right way to be a responsible web designer/owner in 2022, or valid options to choose between? (2) In future, can a more restrictive method be applied to the specific feedback page on the site, or would one explicit page mean rating the site as a whole as explicit?

Comment: I agree this could be clearer stated. But if its clearer, would you feel those 2 are valid to include both of them?

Comment: "What's the right way to be a responsible web designer/owner in 2022" is an example of something that is very broad.  I think you actually mean "What's the right way to be a responsible web designer/owner in 2022 to get my site classified as adult content?" which is answerable.

Comment: Stephen covered it. If the question is broad it will lead to discussion and opinion instead of concrete answers. "How to get my site classified as adult content" is focused and can generate concrete answers.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. I figured the "by getting it directly registered/classified with appropriate major lists, or including appropriate important tags" was enough context... Would people _really_ have read it as a question about how to be a responsible website manager in 2022 in every way one could be?! It never occurred to me the question could be considered separate from the obvious focus of the question. Or am I misunderstanding this still? Useful learning point either way?

Comment: Anyway got enough to have a go, but a bit of continued comment here will probably help me understand more about being on track with less hand holding, for future, so I'd still value this thread to continue a bit.

Comment: **Update** - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/139194 . The question is narrow, and my research and other info is clearly distinct. Acceptable way to word it? If so, thanks for the guidance and hand holding here that made it possible. If not, help to understand any fixes needed?

Comment: I just had to close the question as it had at least nine questions within it. Can you please narrow it down to the one question at hand?